# Coping with losing SD card access while app is running

Tags: java, android, mobile

My bitmap editor app uses the SD card to store application data where e.g. I autosave the document state to the SD card every 30 seconds. I know that when the user plugs their phone into their computer, the SD card cannot be accessed by applications any more if the SD card gets mounted on the computer. I need to make sure my application behaves predictably when this happens. I have a couple of queries:

- What happens if I'm in the middle of a function call that is writing to a file when the phone is plugged in? Does Android give me a chance to finish up writing to the file or does the transfer get interrupted?
- Is there any way to get a warning that SD card access is about to be lost to give my app a chance to save its state to disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android uses intents to broadcast actions across the system; in this case with [ACTION_MEDIA_EJECT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MEDIA_EJECT).  This should give your app warning to save it's state to disk.

What happens if you are in a middle of a function call? well that depends how you implemented your function; and can range from silently failing to save file, to crashing the app

Comment: If you still have an open file handle to the SD card at the time (post-warning) when it is actually unmounted, your app will be killed so that the unmounting can proceed.

Comment: good info, do you perhaps know how much time is given between warnning and killing app?

Comment: @Chris: Do you have a linked to any documentation about this behaviour? I haven't read this anywhere before.